# Add a new tab and move the existing grid as a tabitem in Journal Transactions screen

Tags: acumatica

I have tried to add a tab and drag the existing grid to the tabitem in Journal transaction screen, so that i can add another tabitem and a custom grid. Somehow I am unable to do that.

I tried using the edit ASPX by pasting an updated content information. It too doesnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot drag the existing grid as it is not a part of customization.
So, the only way I see here is to create Tab control with your own grid (you can just copy the aspx of the existing grid) and remove the original grid.

[image]

It's not very good solution as if the Acumatica change something in that grid you'll have to merge these changes to your customization manually.
However, I don't think there is another way to achieve this.

Comment: yea, i actually did the same. Thanks for your response.

Comment: After i did this, when it comes to import scenarios, it says cannot automate this screen. What can be the reason?

Comment: Did you create a new import scenario after this modification or use existing one? I think existing scenario cannot find required grid after it was moved to another container.

Comment: I am trying to create a new one.but getting that issue

Comment: Did you encounter?

Comment: No. I think you have to create support request for acumatica team in this case. Look like a bug.

Comment: oh previously i just hide the acumatica grid instead of deleting. that was why i got this issue. After deletig it, it seems working.